# Calculating values with overlapping periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have a query that generates a monthly report for drivers evaluations. Some drivers may not have reports for some months. The reports contain various of violations, one of these violations is a monthly cumulated violation, and it resets every year *which is done in in separate query*. Everything where working just fine, except when the client added a new requirement to this part. The requirement is to change it from resetting every year, to resetting any violation that passed 180 days during the year.

Here is a report's sample (for one driver report):

```
RN                   ReportId             DriverId             StartDate               EndDate                 Level1Vio   Lv1YTD
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- -----------
1                    64                   2073                 2020-10-21 00:00:00.000 2020-11-21 23:59:59.000 1           1
2                    65                   2073                 2020-11-24 05:13:04.133 2020-12-24 05:13:04.133 0           1
3                    67                   2073                 2020-12-23 06:53:52.870 2021-01-23 06:53:52.870 0           1
4                    68                   2073                 2021-01-22 06:33:43.127 2021-02-22 06:33:43.127 0           1
5                    69                   2073                 2021-02-23 04:02:58.680 2021-03-23 04:02:58.680 1           2
6                    70                   2073                 2021-03-22 23:39:33.570 2021-04-22 23:39:33.570 0           2
7                    71                   2073                 2021-04-22 00:28:35.230 2021-05-22 00:28:35.230 0           2
8                    72                   2073                 2021-05-22 15:46:21.767 2021-06-22 15:46:21.767 1           3
9                    73                   2073                 2021-06-25 06:42:02.130 2021-07-25 06:42:02.130 1           4
10                   76                   2073                 2021-07-23 17:42:01.533 2021-08-23 17:42:01.533 0           4
```

The old query that where working was (generates the above sample) :

```
SELECT 
    RN
,   ReportId
,   DriverId
,   StartDate
,   EndDate
,   Level1Vio
,   Lv1YTD = SUM(Level1Vio) OVER(PARTITION BY DriverId ORDER BY ReportId ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
FROM Report
```

The excepted result should be (for the new requirement):

```
RN                   ReportId             DriverId             StartDate               EndDate                 Level1Vio   Lv1YTD
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- -----------
1                    64                   2073                 2020-10-21 00:00:00.000 2020-11-21 23:59:59.000 1           1
2                    65                   2073                 2020-11-24 05:13:04.133 2020-12-24 05:13:04.133 0           1
3                    67                   2073                 2020-12-23 06:53:52.870 2021-01-23 06:53:52.870 0           1
4                    68                   2073                 2021-01-22 06:33:43.127 2021-02-22 06:33:43.127 0           1
5                    69                   2073                 2021-02-23 04:02:58.680 2021-03-23 04:02:58.680 1           2
6                    70                   2073                 2021-03-22 23:39:33.570 2021-04-22 23:39:33.570 0           2
7                    71                   2073                 2021-04-22 00:28:35.230 2021-05-22 00:28:35.230 0           1
8                    72                   2073                 2021-05-22 15:46:21.767 2021-06-22 15:46:21.767 1           2
9                    73                   2073                 2021-06-25 06:42:02.130 2021-07-25 06:42:02.130 1           3
10                   76                   2073                 2021-07-23 17:42:01.533 2021-08-23 17:42:01.533 0           3
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/06287/1)

**Explanation**

If you take `ReportId = 64` *(Nov 2020 Report)* the driver has a registered violation, which should be removed after 180 days, and then in `ReportId = 69`*(Mar 2021 Report)* got another violation. The first violation should end at `ReportId = 71`*(May 2021 Report)* and the second one should be removed at `ReportId = 76`*(Aug 2021 Report)*. This principle is applied on each violation.

**Trys**
I'm trying hard to avoid `cursor` and `while` loops actually, but I couldn't find a way to do this under one query `SELECT` like what I did in the above query. I've tried `CTE` and joins, but with no luck. Everything forces me to use loops, which I try to avoid (because of performance issues). I'm sure there is a way to solve it with simple `SELECT`, but I'm out of thoughts. So, any thoughts or solutions would be much appreciated.

Comment: How does this currently reset every year? Your current query appears to just sum all the previous violations.

Comment: @DaleK fiddle has been added.

Comment: @EdmCoff I've forgot to mention this part is done in separate query, which is out of this question scope. I added this note in the question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of window functions, we can just join with the records which overlap by 180 days.

Updated fiddle: [Working Test Case](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/06287/15)

```
SELECT t1.rn, t1.ReportId, t1.DriverId, t1.StartDate, t1.EndDate, t1.Level1Vio
     , SUM(t2.Level1Vio) AS Lv1YTD
  FROM Report AS t1
  JOIN Report AS t2
    ON t1.StartDate BETWEEN t2.StartDate AND DATEADD(day, 180, t2.StartDate)
   AND t1.DriverId = t2.DriverId
 GROUP BY t1.rn, t1.DriverId, t1.ReportId, t1.StartDate, t1.EndDate, t1.Level1Vio
 ORDER BY t1.StartDate
;
```

Note: I used 180 days from the start of the reported violation.  Adjust as needed.

Also note: I included a version which uses a CTE term.  You can use that if you wish to filter the rows of interest on both sides of the join more conveniently, restricting them to a specific year, or just add that year restriction to the join logic or add a `WHERE` clause.

There are quite a few ways to include the year logic all within this query, without resorting to separate queries to generate per year.